# Binary numbers returns all 0

Tags: python, web-scraping, binary-data

I'm trying to convert my web scraping data into binary numbers. Basically, if the class name contains `yes` it is equal to `1` and `no` is equal to `0`. When I print out the binary_value, it returns all 0 even though it contains `yes`. I'm not really sure what am I missing. Highly appreciated in advance.

```
import cfscrape

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()

response = scraper.get('https://www.hipflat.co.th/projects/ruam-rudee-penthouse-lvukdc')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x and ("amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in x or "amenities__icon amenities__icon--no" in x))

# Convert the elements to binary numbers

for div in divs:
  if "amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in div['class']:
    binary_value = 1
  else:
    binary_value = 0
    
  print(binary_value)
```

the result appears in the terminal when `print(div)`

```
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
<div class="amenities__icon amenities__icon--no"></div>
```

Comment: Your [mre] should include a minimal example of the data also. We should not have to access an offsite resource to reproduce your problem or test solutions.

Comment: Have you debugged by printing `div['class']` in loop?

Comment: I had attached an example of the data. Apologize for my missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: it would be shorter to get `divs` using [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```py
divs = soup.select('div.amenities__icon:is(.amenities__icon--yes, .amenities__icon--no)')
```

---

> ```py
>   if "amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in div['class']:
> ```

<sub>You can actually just check **`if "amenities__icon--yes" in div['class']`** since every `div` should have `amenities__icon` anyway - the `lambda` expression ensures it.</sub>

None of the items in `div['class']` (which can be expected to be a list of strings) will have any spaces, since [HTML classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Howto/CSS_FAQ#how_do_i_assign_multiple_classes_to_an_element) are *separated* by spaces, and when BeautifulSoup parses them, they are split into a list. (It becomes quite obvious if you just [print the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o67iI.png) with `for div in divs: print(div['class'])`.)

So, the correct way to check for both `amenities__icon` and `amenities__icon--yes` classes would be

```py
  if "amenities__icon" in div['class'] and "amenities__icon--yes" in div['class']:
```

or, if you wanted that specific order for some reason, you could [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) the classes back into a single string before checking

```py
  if "amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in " ".join(div['class']):
```

---

If you use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```py
[int("amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in " ".join(d['class'])) for d in divs] # OR
# [1 if "amenities__icon amenities__icon--yes" in " ".join(d['class']) else 0 for d in divs]
```

would return `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`.